# Notation for real space

Tags: differential-geometry

In the definition of a (0, k)-tensor $\xi:TM^{k}\to \mathbb{R}_{M}$, how can we read this notation $\mathbb{R}_{M}$? Is this a real space defined on M?

Comment: No, it should just be $\mathbb R$.

Comment: It is the trivial bundle on $M$, $\mathbb R_M = M \times \mathbb R$.